# Hololens Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2015, unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

I am trying to run a sample project from unity to vs2015. There when I started debugging in Hololens Emulator, I get this error:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app  'HoloLensSample_p.......App'.
>   The HoloLensSample.exe process started, but the activation request
>   failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target
>   application. this usually indicates that the target application's
>   process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane
>   of the Output window'

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How to run the app in hololens emulator?. I followed this link [ https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_101e ] to run the app, while doing so i am getting those kinds of error. Kindly help me to fix the problem.

Comment: I had this problem, and I went with the tried a true restart everything approach and it is working great now.

Comment: Hi, Rob A, Thanks for your reply, Anyway i tried for more than 5 to 6 times but its not working for me...

Comment: I have improved some of the markup and wording of your question. If there is any more information you can add to the question to give some context to this error, that would be useful too.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, Mr. Vince Bowdren. Check this link ( http:https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.debug.error.app_activation_failure);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true )

Answer (score 0):

This article tells you how to setup for debugging using a tutorial this should give you the information you need to debug your own project.

Following these instructions,

1) "In Visual Studio, right click on Package.appxmanifest in the Solution Explorer and select View Code.

2) Find the line specifying TargetDeviceFamily and change Name="Windows.Universal" to Name="Windows.Holographic". On the same line, change MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" to MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0" Save the Package.appxmanifest."

3) In Visual Studio go to Project->*YourProjectName* Properties, click on Debug on the sidebar.

4) check the box that states "Uninstall and then re-install my package. All information about the application state is deleted"

This should allow you to run in debug mode, however like I said in my comments, the newest version of Unity for Hololens have debugging built into it now.